# Bare bones battleship game

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, game

This is basically the beginnings of a battleship game. There is only 1 ship which takes up 3 of six locations on a 1 x 6 grid. The locations are created by finding a random location on the grid and then taking the next two points as the other 2 locations.

I basically just make sure the the guess is between 1 and 6, make sure the number has not been guessed before by comparing it to `guessarr` (an array that contains all the valid guesses), then compare the guess to the random locations to determine if it's a hit or miss. After guessing all 3 random locations, the user wins.

How would I go about making this code object-oriented?

```
var guess;
var guesses = 0;
var hits = 0;
var isSunk = false;
var  guessCheck=-1;
var guessarr = [];
var valid = true;
var randomeloc = Math.floor(Math.random () * 5);
var location1 = randomeloc
var location2 = randomeloc + 1;
var location3 = randomeloc +2;


while (isSunk == false) {
    guess = prompt("Enter a guess between 1 and 6");
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
        alert("Enter a valid number between 0 and 6");
    }else if(guess > 0 || guess < 6) {
        guessCheck= guessarr.indexOf(guess);
        if (guessCheck >= 0) {
        valid = false;
        alert("You've already entered this number. Try again");
        } else if (valid = true){
            guesses = guesses +1;
            if (guess == location1 ||
                guess == location2 ||
                guess == location3) {
                hits = hits + 1;
                alert ("You got a hit!");
                guessarr.push(guess);
            }                   
            else {alert("miss");
            }
            if (hits == 3) {
            isSunk= true;
            alert("you won!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ship must be in consecutive sectors.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it as a 2D array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful that the random can be between 0 and 4 when it should be between 1 and 4. If you want to make it more object oriented, I would separate the interface (alert and prompt) from the game logic. As this is just a game with 1 ship, I would only do a Game and Ship objects to represent it, but for more complex versions other objects may apply. Here is how I would implement it having custom columns:

```
function Game(columns){
  this.guesses;
  this.guessarr;
  this.columns = columns;
  this.ship;
  this.ended;

  return this;
}

Game.prototype.getRandomNumber = function(min,max){ // interval [)
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

Game.prototype.getRandomShipPosition = function(shipSize){
  return this.getRandomNumber(1,this.columns - shipSize + 2);
}

Game.prototype.init = function(){
  this.guesses = 0;
  this.guessarr = [];
  this.ship = new Ship(this.getRandomShipPosition(3), 3);
  this.ended = false;
}

Game.prototype.makeGuess = function(guess){
  if(isNaN(Number(guess))){
      return "Enter a valid number";
  }
  if(guess <= 0 || guess > this.columns){
      return "Guess has to be between 1 and " + this.columns;
  }
  if(this.guessarr.indexOf(guess) != -1){
      return "You've already entered this number. Try again";
  }
  this.guessarr.push(guess);
  if(this.ship.makeGuess(guess)){
      if(this.ship.isSunk){
          this.ended = true;
      }
      return "You got a hit!";
  }else{
      return "Miss";
  }
}

function Ship(start,size){
  this.start = start;
  this.hits = 0;
  this.size = size;
  this.isSunk = false;

  return this;
}

Ship.prototype.makeGuess = function(guess){
    if(guess >= this.start && guess <= this.start + this.size){
        this.hits+=1;
        if(this.hits == this.size){
            this.isSunk = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


var game = new Game(6);
game.init();
while(game.ended == false){
    guess = Number(prompt("Enter a guess between 1 and 6"));
    alert(game.makeGuess(guess))
}
alert("you won!")
```